# How to output unique keys with MultiMap from Guava? (Java)

Tags: java, hashmap, key, guava, multimap

I've got the following method:

```
public static void showStuff(Multimap<String, String> map) {
        for (String key : map.keys()) {
            System.out.println("The key, " + key
                    + ", has the results: " + map.get(key));
        }
    }
```

This outputs:

```
The key, **one**, has the results: [a,b,c,d,d,e]
The key, **one**, has the results: [a,b,c,d,d,e]
The key, **one**, has the results: [a,b,c,d,d,e]
The key, **one**, has the results: [a,b,c,d,d,e]
The key, **one**, has the results: [a,b,c,d,d,e]
The key, **two**, has the results: [a,a,a,b,b,e]
The key, **two**, has the results: [a,a,a,b,b,e]
```

How would I have it only output unique keys. I want it to only printout the statement once rather than repeat it multiple times. I have a table with different rows with duplicate keys, hence I used the MultiMap to get all the values for a duplicated key. How will I now output only

```
The key, **one**, has the results: [a,b,c,d,d,e]
The key, **two**, has the results: [a,a,a,b,b,e]
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Multimap.keySet()` to get just the distinct keys.

You can use `Multimap.entries()` to get the (key, values) pairs, rather than having to go back to the map to request the values associated with each key.

Alternatively, you can use `Multimap.asMap()` to convert it to a `java.util.Map`, and then work with that instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use `map.keySet()` instead of `map.keys()`